# A divergent Matsubara frequency summation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions

There is a [table of Matsubara frequency summations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency#Table_of_Matsubara_frequency_summations). The 8th one, $$\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i\omega}\frac{(i\omega)^2}{(i\omega)^2-\xi^2}=-\frac{\xi}{2}(1+2\eta n_\eta(\xi))$$ with $\eta=\pm1$ for boson/fermion, is somewhat weird simply because it looks to be divergent at all. Is it obtained with some regularization scheme or anything else?

Comment: Yes, regularization was used. The result actually depends on the regularization scheme. See related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/which-limit-for-matsubara-frequency-summation?rq=1

Comment: @EverettYou Thank you. I actually have tried your frequency summation program which uses $\mathrm{e}^{-\delta z}$ to control the convergence. But it turns out that the result doesn't depend on which control plane we set. Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @houtuichang Well... I think it is a special case, the bare result was $\eta\xi/2(n_\eta(-\xi)-n_\eta(\xi))$. Changing the regularization scheme correspond to $n_\eta(\xi)\to n_\eta(\xi)+C$ where $C$ is an arbiary constant. But in this expression, the constant $C$ from both disribution functions cancles.